# How do you determine the number of ejected electrons based on the photon flux?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, electromagnetic-radiation

If you have a light source with a frequency higher than a materials Electron binding energy, what percent of the photons will eject electrons?

Comment: If the frequency/energy is greater than the energy needed to ionize then wouldn't that mean 100% if we ignore quantum probabilities?

Comment: @gemmima I don’t know if it means 100% or not. Also with angle of incidence affect the percentage?

Comment: Also lots of scattering depending on the depth in the material. A hard problem in general.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks I was thinking something like that. So if you had 1 billion photons per second hitting a surface and all of them had energy above and beyond the binding energy. And you knew everything about the material and the angle of incident, there anyway in general to calculate the percentage?